# Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'D:/a/1/s/EP&T Global/target/cucumber-reports.json

Tags: azure, maven, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, cucumber

I am trying to run the script in the azure devops with pipeline creation but facing issue :

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'D:/a/1/s/EP&T Global/target/cucumber-reports.json

for this I have already set the path of json file in the pipeline

I have tried different pipeline and addons

And I am expecting to run my script successfully

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @HiralPandya, may i know if there's any update? You can follow the sample in my reply for a check. If the issue persists, you can share the issue code snippet for further checking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running `js script` with a devops `Windows` agent.

I can reproduce the error with simple code below:
[image]

[image]

The error is caused by that you specified json file while not directory for the path. Can fix as below:

[image]

Hence, please check the path defined in your script and pipeline definition, make sure it's directory used.